# how to query in firebase select condition where date is datenow

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query in my flutter application to show the user's input data that sort by date now. I have tried this

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getUserWorshipSnapshots(BuildContext context) async*{
//final Long server_timestamp = new DateTime.now().isUtc;
var currentTime = new DateTime.now();
final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
final uid = user.uid;
yield* Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(uid).collection('worship').orderBy('dateTime')
.startAt(currentTime).snapshots();}
```

[image], and my firebase structure is like this [image]. is there any idea? thank you

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do not show pictures of code.  Copy the code into the question itself and format it so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: please add the code as text not as image

Comment: okay. i'm sorry. have already edited

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `users` collection and not a `user` collection, therefore add the missing `s`:

```
yield* Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).collection('worship').orderBy('dateTime')
```

Comment: thank you, my typo. yes but the main problem still the same here. still cannot shows the collection of worship based on current datenow.

Comment: Are you able to retrieve any data? Did u check if uid is null

Comment: Yes, it shows data from firebase. The problem is I just want it to shows the data where the data for the current date. Not the day before.